# Mahapps, themes not applying to user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a single MetroWindow which loads with default Color. I have an option for user to change the style. In the window I use a Content control to set the user control dynamically from code behind when initializing this window (This window is initialized from another application so there is no app.xaml and I use the resources in the window itself). The code of the main windows is below. In the User Control I am using some labels and a tab control. On the window I have an option for user to be able to change the theme choosing from available themes (as in your demo project). In all labels I use dynamics resources.

When the window loads for first time the default color is applied and all inner controls have the same theme as well. When I change the theme from window top, the window border, title, glow changes but the inner control stays the old theme (like the tab control headers etc.) I have tried everything but that does not seem to change.

Below is my code:

```
    <Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300" ShowMaxRestoreButton="False" ShowMinButton="False" 
            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource HighlightBrush}"
            GlowBrush="{DynamicResource HighlightBrush}" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
            ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowTransitionsEnabled="False" TitleCaps="True"
            BorderThickness="1">
    <Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/Test;component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

        <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <ContentControl x:Name="ChildContentControl"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            </ContentControl>
        </Border>
    </Controls:MetroWindow>
```

My code behind for the window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Initialize();
    }

    public MainWindow(string title, UserControl childControl)
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Title = title;
            this.ChildContentControl.Content = childControl;
        }
        catch (Exception de)
        {
            throw de;
        }
    }
}
```

My User control XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UCDemo"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Test;component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>


  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Border>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" LastChildFill="True">

        <Grid Height="60" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">

          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Button Grid.Column="1"  Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="50" Height="50"
              Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding OKCommand}">
            <Rectangle Width="20"
               Height="20"
               Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
              <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                     Visual="{StaticResource appbar_check}" />
              </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.Resources>
              <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.xaml" />
            </Grid.Resources>
            <TabControl Margin="0,10,0,0" TabStripPlacement="Left"  ItemsSource="{Binding Catalogs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCatalog}">
              <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <!-- this is the header template-->
                <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CaptionCat}" Foreground="{DynamicResource HighlightBrush}" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                </DataTemplate>
              </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
              <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SelectedCatalog.Books,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
                      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                        <Controls:Tile Height="125" Width="300" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" Title="{Binding CaptionBook}"/>
                      </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                  </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
              </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

      </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
  </Border>


</UserControl>
```

My User control Code behind:

```
public partial class UCDemo : UserControl
{

    private VMDemo CatalogVM { set; get; }

    public UCDemo()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new VMDemo();
        }
        catch (Exception de)
        {
            throw de;
        }
    }
}
```

And Finally here is how I call the window and embedded user control from hosted application code:

```
private void ShowDemoUI()
    {
        try
        {
            var child = new UILibrary.UCDemo();
            UILibrary.MainWindow window = new UILibrary.MainWindow("Book catalog", child);
            window.Height = 450;
            window.Width = 700;
            window.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception de)
        {
            throw de;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your UserControl and the Code behind?

Comment: @David :  I have modified the main post and added all relevant codes - Shankar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have 2 options to solve this.

- Create your `Test.UCDemo` as DataTemplate for the `VMDemo` type and pass the `VMDemo` for this template to the `Content`, so your `ContentControl` will automatically do the magic for you (it's just only a suggestion, i don't tested it)
- Put the resources in your `Test.UCDemo` too.

Comment: I am using code. So I went with the option 2 and that works. Thanks :)

Comment: @Shankar what did you do to fix this? I'm having the same problem. I've tried adding all the MahApps resources into my user control but the colours still don't update when I change the accent (via the ThemeManager).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all your ResourceDictionaries in the `App.xaml`

After that I think you need to look at the [Theme Manager](http://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html#thememanager).

Here is what I've done. In this example all my `Content Control` have the save `Theme` even if I change the Theme with a button click:

```
public ShellView()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var theme = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);
    ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent("Blue"), theme.Item1);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var theme = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);
    ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent("Cyan"), theme.Item1);
}
```

The code need to be in the code behing of your Window (In my case it's ShellView.cs) for you I will assume that it's MainWindow.cs

Here is an other example with a [Custom Theme](http://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html#custom).

```
public ShellView()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ThemeManager.AddAccent("YourAccent", new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourAccent.xaml"));

    // Set your Custom Theme when the Window start
    var theme = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);
    ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent("YourAccent"), theme.Item1);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Change the Theme to Cyan on a simple button click
    var theme = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);
    ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent("Cyan"), theme.Item1);
}
```

Comment: I do not have an app.xaml. It is mentioned in my original post. My WPF project is WPF class library not an WPF application. I call it from another application. So I do not have the App.xaml. I Infact do not have the application object (Application.Current is null), so for chaning theme I use "ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(this, ThemeManager.GetAccent("Cyan"), theme.Item1);"  where this is the window object. I even tried initializing the Application object  (by new Application()) and adding the resources by code but that also did not work.

Comment: BTW, I am using the ThemeManager to change the Theme, the exact code that is given above. But it only changes the Window theme and not the inner ContentControl embedded usercontrol.